# Avoid redirects in PHP files with no extensions

Tags: php, redirect

In my application, if I attempt to browse to `yellowandred.in/vblogs/index`, I get redirected to the `vblogs` page. I am, instead, intending to load the `index` page - which is a PHP page with no extension.

What is the best way to avoid this redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Put this line on top of your .htaccess or in httpd.conf:

```
Options -MultiViews
```